# How to print libssl and libnspr version from c++ code?

Tags: c++, libssl

How can I print the version of libssl and libnspr  in c++ code ?
I want to print version for both defined in header and library .

Answer (score 1):

The header file opensslv.h #define 's the macro variable OPENSSL_VERSION_TEXT, describing the version. For instance "OpenSSL 0.9.8o-fips 01 Jun 2010".

For the library itself, the name of the lib file contains the version number. In ubuntu, in the folder /lib/, the file is called libssl.so.0.9.8. If you felt like it, you could use boost::filesystem to grab the particular filename and then parse it, perhaps using boost::regex.

Comment: I want to print ssl version on compile time to check with which version it is getting linked.

Comment: In Linux you must install the package openssl-devel:
    `apt-get install openssl-devel` or `yum install openssl-devel`.